# SQL query for faceted search (ALL IN)

Tags: sql, group-by, inner-join, one-to-many

OK, lets assume some simple database.
We have pet table and pet_owner table, pet have its foreign key linked to pet_owner

```
 pet_owner:  
|--id---|-----name-----|  
|   1   |Michael Mayers|  
|   2   |John Doe      |  
|   3   |Markus Tsuker |  
|   4   |Bob Dilan     |  
|   5   |Simon Pegg    |  

 pet:
|--id---|----type---|---owner---|---name---|
|  1    |    dog    |     1     |Billy     |  
|  2    |    cat    |     1     |Willy     |
|  3    |   bird    |     1     |Dilly     |
|  4    |    dog    |     2     |Klaus     |
|  5    |    cat    |     2     |Boss      |
|  6    |    dog    |     3     |Shmat     |
|  7    |    dog    |     4     |Corin     |
|  8    |   fish    |     5     |Suzy      |
|  9    |   dog     |     1     |Mars      |
```

So, the simple task - I need to select people who own CAT and DOG simultaneously. This is a trivial common task for faceted filtration.

The first method:

```
SELECT
pet_owner.name
FROM pet_owner, pet
 WHERE
pet_owner.id = pet.owner AND
pet.type IN ('cat', 'dog')
GROUP BY pet_owner.name
HAVING (COUNT(DISTINCT pet.type) = 2);
```

The second method:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pet_owner.name
FROM pet_owner, pet T1, pet T2
WHERE pet_owner.id = T1.owner
 AND pet_owner.id = T2.owner
 AND T1.type = 'cat'
 AND T2.type = 'dog';
```

Questions:

1. Is there any better SQL query for this task (I suppose, there is)?
2. If not, which is faster? For 10, 100, 1000 unique filters?

Comment: Explicit `join` is better than implicit, comma separated joins

Comment: You can also use `exists` in a couple of ways

Comment: I think the first method will be faster.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Indifferent, really, does not matter. I dont think question is platform-dependent, there is no specific dialect.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Implicit join is exactly cross join with lower precedence, and it makes no sense to say it's faster or slower. What do you mean, "better"?

Comment: The point of needing a DBMS product & version is *exactly* that SQL is a language definition that says nothing about implementation or performance, so your question makes no sense re "SQL".

Answer (score 1):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause; *always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  This is advice so your code looks like it was written in the 21st Century and has no bearing on the actual question.

The normal answer to such a question is to say "try it on your data and see which is faster".

However, for your particular problem, the aggregation method is better.

Let me admit a bias.  I prefer the aggregation method anyway.  A simple modification of the query is all that is needed to change the criteria -- say to require three pets, or to check for birds and dogs.  Or even, cats and dogs, but not birds.

The reason it is better in this case is the `select distinct`.  That is (essentially) going to be doing an aggregation anyway, on top of the joins.  Worse, people can have multiple pets, so the number of rows generated by the joins could be larger than the number of original rows.

In fact, someone might have a puppy factory with a few pet cats thrown in, and really throw off performance of the query using joins.  The puppy factory has minimal impact on the performance of the aggregation query.

If your data started out as distinct (people only being allowed one type of pet) and you were looking for two specific ones, then the `join` query would often have better performance (it still depends on other factors in the data and the database optimizer).  Even so, I still default to the aggregation method for these types of queries, for the reasons outlined above.

Let me also note that I have written some very complex queries in my life.  I don't think I have ever written one that has 1,000 joins in it.  If you are looking at that many items, then `GROUP BY` would be the way to go.  The query would be much simpler.

Comment: Well, I see. I'll try to populate more real data for stress-testing.
And, for example, in Django second way is much easier to realize (nested filter())

Comment: @KirillShatalaev This answer still makes assumptions about implementation/optimization when it addresses "better" performance for "your particular problem", and without them there can be no "better" in the sense of "faster" or other performance aspect. It's DBMS-dependent, not defined by the language.